# How to Loop Through 5 Cells in a Row Using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, excel-2007

I want to loop through 5 cells, Q5 - U5.

With each cell I want to check if the value is equal to "Y", and if yes, highlight the cell to make it green.

How may I do so? Can't seem to figure it out.

```
For Each c In Range("Q5:U5").Cells
c.Select
If c.Value = Y Then
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try to avoid selecting/activating ranges: in 99% of cases there is no need (although the macro recorder always suggests otherwise)

```
For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("Q5:U5").Cells
    If c.Value = "Y" Then
    With c.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5287936
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

When you don't define c as a range, the statement

```
For Each c in ActiveSheet.Range("Q5:U5").Cells
```

while valid, will actually result in `c` having the value of each of the cells.  To solve this problem, declare the type explicitly:

```
Dim c as Range
```

Next, when you do the comparison (as already pointed out), use

```
If c.Value = "Y"
```

Note - if you declare

```
Option Compare Text
```

right at the top of your module, the comparison will be case-insensitive; otherwise, a "Y" will not match a "y".

The whole module would look like this, then:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub colorMe()
Dim c as Range
For Each c In Range("Q5:U5").Cells
  c.Select
  If c.Value = "Y" Then
    With Selection.Interior
      .Pattern = xlSolid
      .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
      .Color = 5287936
      .TintAndShade = 0
      .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

I am sure it doesn't need to be pointed out that you could achieve the same thing with conditional formatting...

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `Y` appears to be an undefined variable.  To check for the value, put it in double quotes:

`If c.Value = "Y" Then`

Comment: Thanks. Fixed that. Debugger tells me there is an error with 'code' c.Select